# Set the value of checkbox into editable field Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUXxM.png)

I am using Image Picker plugin to select the image. I have an empty text area field below images. When user click an image, I want the value/description of that image to automatically copied to that field and also being able to edit.

And when I click un select that image, the field below should become empty.

I have got it working to some extent .

**Problem**

When I select image, the description get's copied into the field. which is fine. But when I un-select the same image, the description still stays there. And when I select different image, the description of different image than doesn't gets copied.

Here is my code.

HTML:
Images come from database.

```
    <select class='image-picker timer-reasons' multiple="multiple" data-limit="1" name="timer-reason-selector" id="timer-reason-selector">
                <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($timer_reasons)) {
                ?>
                    <option data-img-src='../../css/timer-reasons/<?php echo $row['image_tmr']; ?>' style="width:30%;" value='<?php echo $row['description_tmr']; ?>'><?php echo $row['description_tmr']; ?></option>
                <?php 
                     }
                    ?>
            </select>
```

This is field where clicked image description/value should get populated and also editable

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="reason" value="" rows="2"></textarea>
```

**I am using "Image-picker" class**

**JavaScript**

This is my JavaScript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Set up the imagepicker select field
    $("#timer-reason-selector").imagepicker({
        limit:1, 
        hide_select:true, 
        show_label:false,
        limit_reached:function(){           
        }
    });
    

    
        function check_enabled(){

        
        //Get the value of the selected options
        var  timer_reason  = $( "#timer-reason-selector" ).val();

        if (timer_reason !=null){
        $("#reason").text(timer_reason);
        $("#reason").attr('value', timer_reason)
        }else{
            $("#reason").text('');
            $("#reason").attr('value', '')
        }
        
    
    }
        
            //Listen for selection changes and call the check_enabled function
            $( "#timer-reason-selector" ).change(function() {
            
                check_enabled();
            });


        });
    
    
</script>
```

Comment: So what? Did it work or not?

Comment: Hello @xxxmatko. I didn't worked therefore I changed my mind and didn't used this plugin. Instead I did my own coding. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can use `changed` event of `imagepicker` itself like this:

```
$("#timer-reason-selector").imagepicker({
  limit:1, 
  hide_select:true, 
  show_label:false,
  limit_reached:function(){           
  },
  changed: function(select, newValues, oldValues, event) {
    // Do your stuff here
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello @xxxmatko.   Your answer is great and it does work. But I also wanted users to be able to edit the selected value. So when user click an option, the value of that option should appear in text field. Than user can edit than option before pressing save.

Comment: You should be able to access each image / option in that handler and fill your textboxes with it.